# Google+ Playground api not working

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-playground

I'm using Google Playground for accessing Google+ APIs. When I try to call the API

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/[user_id]/circles
```

..then it results in error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits", 
        "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.", 
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In step 1 on the playground page, I've selected both the 'Google+ Domain API' and 'Google+ API v1' and authorized and got the access tokens. Of course, [user_id] is replaced properly before making the API call.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a couple of hours for changes to propagate. You might also try creating a new API key see if it picks up the enabled APIs.

Comment: @abraham it is not working even after many days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reason.
The Google+ Domain APIs are not meant to be accessed without having a domain account configured on Google. After setting the domain account on Google, the administrator needs to set the permissions to allow the access to these APIs.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/